# OctopusDeploy - Every website in the deploy has a different AppPool and Website name; how to deal; no other differences

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy

I'm trying to setup a deploy process that targets 16 web sites each hosting an instance of the same application.

Websites and AppPools are named as such:

appServer1:

app10.site.com

app11.site.com

app12.site.com

app13.site.com

appServer2:

app20.site.com

app21.site.com

app22.site.com

app23.site.com

etc.

etc.

...with each website having a correspondingly named AppPool.

I am desperately trying to determine how to use a single Deploy NuGet Package step to target all of these websites/app pools using variables and a combination of powershell scripts if possible.

I'd like to have a single step where I can variable substitute the website and app pool names. As this is the only difference. I basically need the equivalent of being able to loop the nuget package step passing it a list of website and app pool names. I cannot simply use variables because I can only resolve to the machine level with variable scoping.

Create list of all Website and AppPool names, iterate them passing each value to a Step for execution. ForEach processing step for lack of better words.

I do have the ability to rename the AppPools if need be for a more consistent pattern, but I cannot change the website names

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/3481-every-website-in-the-deploy-has-a-different-apppool-and-website-name-how-to-deal-no-other-differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot to your question, but I'm going to take a stab at explaining *our approach*, in hopes of jogging your creative juices.

#### tl;dr

simply put, use your own powershell scripts to install the web-application. In there you can set the app pool name on a per website basis

---

For starters, *we do* do a separate deployment step for each project. The scripts we use will allow you to do all deployments from a single deploy.ps1 (including unique appPool names), but we find that it really helps keep each deployment nice and lean, and easy to manage. Each project get's it's own nupkg and therein contains the predeploy.ps1, deploy.ps1, and postdeploy.ps1 as well as a folder of [build/deploy scripts that we've open sourcesd](https://github.com/FutureStateMobile/fsm-posh/tree/master/src/devops.build-release), and a folder of environment config xml files.

A sample of an environment config would be this. The name is simply [envName].xml

```xml
<!-- environments\Production.xml -->
<environmentSettings>
    <webSites>
        <app>
            <physicalPathRoot>c:\inetpub</physicalPathRoot>
            <physicalFolderPrefix>appname</physicalFolderPrefix>
            <siteProtcol>https</siteProtcol>
            <siteName>appname.tld</siteName>
            <siteHost>appname.tld</siteHost>
            <portNumber>443</portNumber>
            <appPath>/</appPath>
            <appPool>
                <name>appname.tld</name>
                <!-- valid identityTypes are: [LocalSystem, LocalService, NetworkService, SpecificUser, ApplicationPoolIdentity] -->
                <identityType>NetworkService</identityType>
                <!-- Set this value to the User the Service will run under in the format DOMAIN\username -->
                <!-- If Running as 'NetworkService' then 'NT AUTHORITY\Network Service' is used -->
                <userName>NT AUTHORITY\Network Service</userName>
                <!-- Leave blank unless using SpecificUser -->
                <password></password>
                <maxWorkerProcesses>5</maxWorkerProcesses>
            </appPool>
        </app>
    </webSites>
    <serverDatabase>
        <name>database_name</name>
        <connectionString>REPLACED BY OCTOPUS</connectionString>
        <providerName>System.Data.SqlClient</providerName>
    </serverDatabase>
</environmentSettings>
```

You can see in the corresponding [`Get-EnvironmentSettings.ps1`](https://github.com/FutureStateMobile/fsm-posh/blob/master/src/devops.build-release/Get-EnvironmentSettings.ps1) where we load up the config, and then update it with any Octopus variables. This is the trickiest part, because we use dot-Notation to update the paths (case sensitive).

Our octopus variables really only contain information that is secret, as everything else lives in [environment].xml

```
|   Name                             |     Value            |  Scope
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| webSites.app.appPool.password      |     supersecret      | Production
```

---

So now a typical deployment script simply imports the modules, grab environmentSettings, update config, and install the web app.

```
# Top of the script, get Octopus environment and version
param( 
    [string] $version = $OctopusPackageVersion,
    [string] $environment = $OctopusEnvironmentName
)

# Make sure a failed deployment actually fails
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

# Import the modules
$currentDir = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$moduleDir = "$currentDir\modules"
Import-Module BuildDeployModules

# Grab the environment settings
$environmentSettings = Get-EnvironmentSettings $environment "//environmentSettings"
$databaseSettings = $environmentSettings.serverDatabase
$websiteSettings = $environmentSettings.webSites.app

# update the config
Update-XmlConfigValues $currentDir\website\Web.config "//appSettings/add[@key='databaseName']" $($databaseSettings.name) "value"
Update-XmlConfigValues $currentDir\website\Web.config "//connectionStrings/add[@name='databaseConnection']" $($databaseSettings.connectionString) "connectionString"
Update-XmlConfigValues $currentDir\website\Web.config "//connectionStrings/add[@name='databaseConnection']" $($databaseSettings.providerName) "providerName"

# Install the web application
Install-WebApplication $environment $websiteSettings $version "anonymousAuthentication"
```

In doing all of this, the web application is installed into IIS with a specific application pool, and appropriate config transforms without relying on any unknowns.

Our nupkg structure looks something like this

- appname.1.2.3.4.nupkg

  - environments

    - dev.xml
    - staging.xml
    - qual.xml
    - production.xml
  - modules

    - [all of our build modules]
  - website

    - [all of our website files]

This is super repeatable, easy to maintain, and easy to edit config. Hope it helps

Comment: great ideas and info.  I appreciate it.  Marking you as the answer.  Since posting this originally, I have gained much Octopus knowledge and abilities.  It's a great tool for sure.

Mixing in some psake is a good thing also.  :)